# MySql: can I put up data fence between multiple connections?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, f#

I have multiple threads inserting rows into 2 tables, one with foreign key (FK) and one with primary key (PK), using F# SqlDataProvider. Each insert gets its own data context (connection).

I make sure that I insert into table with PK and SubmitUpdates(), and then and only then do I create another context (in another thread) to insert data into table with FK.

For some reason, this has a race condition: sometimes transaction fails with FK constraint failure, even though data is in the database already, and I see in the log that SubmitUpdates() was properly called a few milliseconds before.

I'm sure SubmitUpdates() waits for database to confirm that transaction commit succeeded, otherwise nothing would ever work. However it seems that even if I create a new data context (connection) *after* that and try to commit dependent rows into table with FK, that thread/connection for some reason isn't immediately seeing the data that has just been successfully committed in another thread. If I confine all that activity to one thread, it all works.

Am I missing something here? What's the way to diagnose such issue?

[Edit] It looks like there's a lag when data is committed, before it's available on another thread/connection. If I operate within the same connection (data context) or if I just wait for 1 second and re-submit my queries when they fail (that doesn't happen often), they succeed. I guess I'll have to accept that multiple connections, even within the same process, are not serializable in the sense that I cannot put a data fence between two connections and make sure that connection B is always guaranteed to see all data committed in connection A.

Comment: You may be seeing an issue with MySql isolation levels, I believe that the default isolation level for MySql is Repeatable Read and this can lead to issues such as your seeing where an insert isn't visible to another connection.  See https://blog.pythian.com/understanding-mysql-isolation-levels-repeatable-read/

Comment: On its face the isolation levels shouldn't play a role because I start new transaction after old transaction committed.
However, there may be a bug where the new transaction, unbeknownst to me, starts earlier. E.g. if the session manager coalesces multiple transactions into one or some such. 
So, you might be right! I'm not sure how to check it though, short of debugging LINQ source code. Is there a way to make MySQL or LINQ to log all requests in all sessions in a way that would make it clear if transactions from different sessions overlap in time?

Comment: Simply setting isolation level to read uncommitted won't cut it, unfortunately. Even if nothing fails, I can't be sure it doesn't fail simply because the latency on MySql became shorter due to fewer queues and buffers used to isolate transactions. So, even if bug disappears, it won't prove anything.